# Calling external Macro in static lib

Tags: objective-c

EDIT:

My xCode project (called PROJECT1) contains another xCode project as a dependency (in Build Phases) (called LIB1)

The problem I have is that LIB1 needs a macro and some defines defined at compile time by PROJECT1 in an include (depending on what target is selected in PROJECT1)

I thought that a Run script action could help me. But I discovered that the script is called after dependencies are built. So my include file is copied into my lib source code, after that the lib is compiled...

Also I discovered that build settings environment variables are not transmitted to LIB1, which would help me a lot.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Thierry

Comment: Buy it glasses?  Macros are not "called", they are "expanded".  They must be present when the code is compiled (or, more precisely, pre-processed), and changing the macro after the compile will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the header file that contains the stuff you need in the code that needs it. A macro isn't like a function where you're jumping to code at another location. A macro creates code in the place where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to turn all your dependencies into variables/methods rather than macro literals or macro function expansions.  Generally this would be via a separate services module provided for each distinct operating environment.